# Homestead - Error Setting VM

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I'm currently Setting Up Homestead for **Laravel** in Windows.

-already installed VirtualBox and Vagrant.

-enabled virtual machine in BIOS

-no "tab" in my .YAML file only spaces

So far that's all the problem i've solved.

I've run:

```
homestead up
```

but it returns an error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
←[K==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'unknown' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.

If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
VirtualBox GUI is open.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you start the machine manually (from the GUI)? This error message is usually indicative of VIrtualBox issues.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically happens because "VT-x" is disabled in your BIOS Setting.

First, make sure it's enabled and re-run it. if you still getting the same error try run in VM GUI. you will receive pop-up of the error.

Still, in the error message they provide some nice tips for you.

> if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the VirtualBox GUI
>   is open.

Once your VM is working run 'vagrant up' normally.